# Explicitly state Sort properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement pagination and sorting of an HTTP request using Spring's Pageable. Everything works fine except I would like to explicitly state sortable properties, i.e. the resource has properties `id`, `name`, `created`.
The default implementation allows users to call the HTTP request and sort the results by all the properties. However, I would like to limit the sorting only to columns `id` and `name`.

Below is an example of my current code

```
@GetMapping("/items")    
public Page<ItemDto> getItems(Pageable pageable) {
  return itemsRepository.findAll(pageable).map(itemsMapper::toItemDto);
}
```

The obvious solution would be to retrieve the `Sort` object from the `Pageable` and validate the properties manually like this

```
@GetMapping("/items")    
public Page<ItemDto> getItems(Pageable pageable) {
  pageable.getSort().forEach(order -> {
    if (!StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(order.getProperty(), "id", "code") {
      // throw exception
    }
  }
return itemsRepository.findAll(pageable).map(itemsMapper::toItemDto);
```

}

My question is if in Spring exists a simpler way of sorting only by explicitly defined properties.

Answer (score 0):

For just creating a pageable which sorts the found items only by `id` and `name` you can use the following snippet or in other words, access the repository like:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by("id", "name"));
itemsRepository.findAll(pageable);
```